# R DataTable Quotient For Groups

Tags: r, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("Group"=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
"Class"=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
"Score"=c(6,7,7,4,8,8,3,4),
"Q"=c(0.857142857,0.857142857,1.75,1.75,1,1,0.75,0.75))
```

I have data with all but 'Q' columns. To get to 'Q' I divide Score for Class 0 by Score for Class 1 for Each Group. I wish to generate column 'Q' and add it to data1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in multiple ways (assuming that there would be only one value of 0 and 1 in 'Score' for each group, do a comparison operator and subset the 'Score' corresponding to each 'Class'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[,  Q1 := Score[Class == 0]/Score[Class == 1] , Group]
```

Or another option is `order` and divide the first/last

```
setDT(data1)[order(Group, Class), Q1 = first(Score)/last(Score), Group]
```

Comment: thank you i was stuck on this for quite a long time

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `order` + `ave`

```
df <- within(df[order(df$Group,df$Class),],
             Q <- ave(Score,Group,FUN = function(v) v[1]/v[2]))
```

such that

```
> df
  Group Class Score         Q
1     1     0     6 0.8571429
2     1     1     7 0.8571429
3     2     0     7 1.7500000
4     2     1     4 1.7500000
5     3     0     8 1.0000000
6     3     1     8 1.0000000
7     4     0     3 0.7500000
8     4     1     4 0.7500000
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), Class = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Score = c(6, 7, 7, 4, 8, 8, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
```